# Install the latest version of KeePass

Tags: software-installation, ppa, plugins, keepass

I installed KeePass2

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install keepass2
```

and I copy plugin to KeePass to plugin KeePass folder and if I open KeePass I have this error:

```
Plugin is not loaded
A newer KeePass version is required to open this file
```

Can you help me?
I Use Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [other PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/keepass2?field.series_filter=focal), it ships 2.48 version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/keepass2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Temporary Manual Official Solution - 20.04

> keepass2 PPA has not been updated for a quiet a while.
> So follow the steps to update manually to Version **2.48.1 or latest**

### Download

Download portable version zip file from **Official link**
https://keepass.info/download.html

> **Unzip** and copy the file **KeePass.exe**

### Replace File

> Close KeePass application if it's open
> Open directory with admin rights `/usr/lib/keepass2`
> Backup keepass2 Folder to safe place in-case things go wrong
> Paste and Replace the KeePass.exe file to the folder

As of Version 2.51.1 you are good to go.